# about installing gimp(flatpak vs software app)

Tags: software-installation, gimp

When I installed gimp with flatpak, I cannot find gimp icon anywhere even when I search for it. So I remove gimp and install gimp again with software application and then gimp shows up.

Why this happend? what is difference between them?
I'm so confused in ubuntu world, what is happening?

Additionally, for asking ubuntu, I thought I can change the line by \n but doesn't work. Can you tell me how to change the line in stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If flatpak is correctly installed on your computer, a launcher in your menu will correctly be installed. After installation, the icon should appear in your menu within seconds. So what you experience is not standard.

Flatpak installs .desktop launchers in a directory `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share`. When you installed flatpak, the parent directory should have been added to the XDG_DATA_DIRS directory. THen, your desktop can find these launchers. Check the contents of that variable with the command `printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS`. If that directory is not there, then somehow the flatpak confguration went not well. Reinstalling flatpak (`sudo apt install flatpak --reinstall`) might then restore that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are no difference from GIMP from the software center (which is probably the snap version) and the flatpak version.

> When I installed gimp with flatpak, I cannot find gimp icon anywhere even when I search for it.

If you just installed Flatpak and installed Gimp after that, it will not show up because flatpak has updated certain files that make flatpak apps show in the app menu. To "complete" the flatpak installation, you will need to restart your computer.

Hope this clears your doubts :)

Comment: Of course I did restart a few times, but nothing change.

Comment: GIMP is currently at version 2.10.30, while the Discover version is at version 2.10.24